# where I should put my "google analytics control" in 'master page' or in 'footer control'

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, google-analytics, master-pages

I have "footer control:(ascx) which is in "master page"
now I have created  "google analytics control" (ascx)

where I need to put/call this "google analytics control" (ascx)
1. In master page ( where I am calling footercontrol.ascx)
2. In footercontrol.ascx ( then only footercontrol.ascx control need to add in master page)

which is right place to add "google analytics control" (ascx) ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible, having nested ascx controls (ascx in another ascx) is not a good idea, therefor locate analytics control in to the master page. This will provide a clear structure of the controls on the page.

In general, you do not need a third party control to track users with Google Analytics. It requires to add a few lines of javascript code and this can be done without an ascx. Login your Google Analytics, get the tracking code and add it directly to the master page.